# Apps are not deployed in the Google Play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have updated an existing app, but it is stuck in this state.
Waiting for 3 days, when will it be completed?

When deployed, I chose a 20% rollout. Does this have anything to do with it? Thank you.

[My App Update State Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMnaA.png)

Comment: in review means you need to wait for google play approval. Could take a week or more in this pandemic...

Comment: Choose the 100% rollout and wait for 30 minutes. Also try to check the play store status from different mobile.

Comment: It can take over 7 days. It shouldn't matter what your roll out percentage is

Comment: Thank you guys. but Is there a correlation between Pandemic and waiting time?

Comment: there is, I believe there's a red colored information above the window that explain slow support in pandemic.